# Can I check if a Union-Member is set?

Tags: c, unions

Having this union and stucts:

```
tydef union{
  TYPE1 t1;
  TYPE2 t2;
  TYPE3 t3;
}myunion;

typedef struct{
   uint8 ID;
   uint8 value;
}TYPE1;

typedef struct{
   uint8 ID;
   uint8 flag;
   long value;
}TYPE2;
```

I would like to execute a function like this:

```
CheckIfSet(&myunion.t1);
```

which works somewhat like this:

```
CheckIfSet(void *test){
  if (test.ID != NULL) then{
   return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

Before executing this check, I am executing another function, which should result in the setup of myunion.t1 - but I need to check if it did happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You have to keep track of which field of a union is active. The backing memory of the union is shared across its fields, so setting one may affect the value of another.

Also, don't forget that accessing an inactive field of a union results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that. There is no such thing as being "set" in pure `C` language. Even if you haven't initialized a variable, it contains some garbage value which belongs to the set of all possible values for that variable type. You have no way of distinguishing whether this is a valid or garbage value.

You need to introduce some kind of flag that will be used for checking the initialization state. E.g., the flag can be initialized to `FALSE` initially and once you set your union, it will be changed to `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

Initialise the value of ID to a value you do not use and test for it.